# How to pause running SetTimeOut Function?

Tags: javascript

When page will finish loading, function "auto" runs. I wrote something like loop and it works well, but I have no idea how to stop this (by mouseover event). 
JS code:

```
document.getElementById("a").addEventListener("mouseover", stop);
if (document.readyState === "complete") {
auto()
}

var d = document.getElementById("a");

function stop() {
    d.style.backgroundColor = "brown"; 
}

function auto() {
    setTimeout(function() {
        d.style.backgroundColor = "blue";

        if (d.style.backgroundColor === 'blue') {
            setTimeout(function() {
                d.style.backgroundColor = "yellow"; 

                if (d.style.backgroundColor === 'yellow') {
                    setTimeout(function() {
                        d.style.backgroundColor = "red";

                        if (d.style.backgroundColor === 'red') {
                            return auto();
                        }

                    }, 1000)
                }
            }, 1000)
        }
    }, 1000)

};
```

I'm looking for solution how to stop color changing after mouseover (for example, when mouseover event is runing when div color is red, function "auto" is disabled and stay in this position). After mouseout, "auto" function should continue "work".
I was thinking about while loop and "return false" inside.

https://jsfiddle.net/qaxu1py2/

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/clearTimeout

Comment: I feel like you could just as easily accomplish this with CSS animations.  What are you actually trying to do?  Do you just want a div that changes colors when your mouse is over it or do you plan to do more with the JS?

Comment: That code runs? I am surprised since colors are normally returned in rgb

Comment: it seems like what you're trying to do is more appropriate for a custom CSS keyframe animation and some hover styling.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can keep track of the latest timeout using a variable, and then cancel the timeout using `clearTimeout`:

```
var timeout;

document.getElementById("a").addEventListener("mouseover", stop);
if (document.readyState === "complete") {
    auto()
}

var d = document.getElementById("a");

function stop() {
    d.style.backgroundColor = "brown";
    clearTimeout(timeout);
}

function auto() {
    timeout = setTimeout(function() {
        d.style.backgroundColor = "blue";

        if (d.style.backgroundColor === 'blue') {
            timeout = setTimeout(function() {
                d.style.backgroundColor = "yellow"; 

                if (d.style.backgroundColor === 'yellow') {
                    timeout = setTimeout(function() {
                        d.style.backgroundColor = "red";

                        if (d.style.backgroundColor === 'red') {
                            return auto();
                        }

                    }, 1000)
                }
            }, 1000)
        }
    }, 1000)

};
```

Comment: This is exactly what I'm looking for. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If all you want is a `<div>` that changes colors, but stops when you mouse over it, you don't even need JavaScript.  You can do it all with [CSS Animations](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Animations/Using_CSS_animations):

```css
.colorize {
  width: 64px;
  height: 64px;
  background-color: blue;
  animation: colorize 3s steps(1) infinite;
}

.colorize:hover {
  animation-play-state: paused;
}

@keyframes colorize {
  0% {
    background-color: blue;
  }
  33% {
    background-color: yellow;
  }
  66% {
    background-color: red;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="colorize"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can put your `setTimeOut` on a variable and use `clearTimeOut()`:

```
var timeOut;

function runTimeout(){
    timeOut = setTimeout(function(){  ..... }, 200);
}

function stopTimeout(){
   clearTimeout(timeOut );
}
```

Or use a **flag** like this:

```
var isRunnig = false;

function runTimeout(){
     isRunnig = true;
     setTimeout(function(){
         if(isRunnig ){
           ....
         }
     },200);
}

function stopTimeout(){
   isRunnig = false;
}
```

[Sources](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_cleartimeout.asp)

Comment: Your answer is very helpful. Thank you.